# Double click title bar to minimize window (as in OS X)?

Tags: windows-vista, double-click

I am an OS X user at home, and now the PC I use in my new job is running Vista.

What I miss from OS X is that I used to double click the title bar to minimize a window, but now that leads to maximize instead. Is there an easy to change this behavior in Windows Vista?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a job for [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). :)

[Here is a script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/WindowShading.htm) for Window Shading, rolling a window up to its title bar.

Comment: AutoHotkey seems like to be a solution. Does anyone know any script doing the function I wanted?

Comment: I'm sure you'll be more than interested in this forum thread: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic16364.html

Comment: Hmm, @Snark, now you have me thinking... I use double-clicking on the title bar constantly, for maximizing/restoring windows. But, this would be very useful for me if I hooked it up to, say, a single middle-click on the title bar. <MrBurns>Excellent...</MrBurns>

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[WinRoll](http://www.palma.com.au/winroll/)** to make a window **roll into its title bar**, send it to the back or make it stay on top. **Minimize**, maximize or close all visible windows, including **minimizing to the tray area**.

[image]

*WinRoll is freeware.*

**[Pitaschio](http://pitaschio.ara3.net/)** will also add this feature.

Open **Setting of Mouse shortcut** in the main window, in the section **Title Bar** you can assign **Roll Up/Down** or **Minimize** to a variety of mouse actions (although 'double click' is not included).

[image]

*Pitaschio is freeware.*

If you want it done via 'double click', then **[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)** does exactly what you want (and a **LOT** more :)

**Window Settings** > **Default Settings** > **Rollup**

Check the box **Via title bar double-click**

[image]

Or go to **Window Settings** > **Default Settings** > **Minimzing** and take your pick from a plethora of options.

[image]

*Actual Window Manager is shareware, try before you buy.*

Comment: the request is about minimizing, not rolling it up! :-)

Comment: duly noted and edited my post accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    ~LButton::
   If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500) {
      WinMinimize A ; minimize windows
   }
Return
```

Try this Autohotkey script :)

Comment: It still has problem with this script . i'll rewrite it this afternoon :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, changing habits isn't my priority since I have been using mac for over ten years. I was given a new mac mini and now I have to find that little yellow button time and time again and it is a real drag. Why would they change it? I can't think of any reason.

Comment: @Natalie, please read the FAQ and note this is not a forum. Thanks! (As an aside, in Mac OS X the double-click behaviour is a preference in System Preferences, Appearance.)